# How do I hide binary files in tmux-sidebar directory tree?

Tags: vim, tmux

Tmux version : 2.5

OS : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Editor : Vim 8.0

I'm using tmux version 2.5 and installed tmux-sidebar with tmux plugin manager `set -g @plugin tmux-plugins/tmux-sidebar` and works great. I use Vim 8.0 as my primary editor to write code and it creates `.swp` and other 
"." files as you can see in the bellow image. I'm not able to figure out how do I hide binary `dot`   files in the directory tree. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is about a feature of `tmux-sidebar`, a good first stop for answers is to check their Github issue tracker.

There I find an open issue noting [the output is not configurable](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sidebar/issues/29).

So your options are to either patch `tmux-sidebar` or use a different solution. Since you mentioned using a vim, you could use it's built-in "netrw" file browser, which includes customizable file hiding. From within vim, use `:help netrw-hiding` to view details.

Future questions about Tmux are not appropriate for the scope of StackOverflow. Ask them on another site in the network like Super User.